# R: Applying quanteda's textstat_readability function producing "Error in set"

Tags: r, readability, quanteda

I am encountering an issue with applying the textstat_readability function to a DF column.  Following several lines of cleaning tweet text (~ 53K observations), I apply the text_readability function to create a new column called $Flesch from the $cleantext column:

measlestweets_readability$read_flesch<-(textstat_readability(measlestweets_readability$cleantext,measure = "Flesch"))$Flesch

**Error Message:**
The resulting error is: "Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) :
Supplied 53380 items to be assigned to 53381 items of column 'read_flesch'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code."

What does this error code mean and how can I begin to resolve it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a well-stated question, but I suspect I know the problem anyway.  As of **quanteda** 2.0.1, `textstat_readability` omits results for empty documents.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

textstat_readability(c("The cat in the hat", "", "Once upon a time."))
##   document  Flesch
## 1    text1 117.160
## 2    text3  97.025
```

So if your `cleantext` field includes an empty string document, then the result will not include it.

You can being to resolve it by creating a corpus from a doc_id variable in your original `measlestweets_readability` data.frame, and then using `dplyr::leftjoin` on that variable from the `document` field in the textstat output to merge in the `Flesch` column.